# Any way to convert database diagrams in sql server 2005 to other formats?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can i convert the diagram to other formats like to Visio (other than copy to clip board command in sql server 2005) or any other utilities to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not, I've been searching for years for this feature.

Would be a nice feature for a future version of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

dont know. but Balsamiq Mockups is a really easy tool for mocking up diagrams (SQL and ER included). check it out - http://www.balsamiq.com/